# Given list of Dictionary of employee information, how to look up by ID number using DICT or combination of LIST when applicable

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, input

Case: I need to get user input of employee ID using `input()` to view employee details contained in a dictionary.

Problem: But the output of `input()` is a string. How can I relate an employee ID to lookup for their information already contained in a dictionary. I try to use LIST but not successful.

Code:

## Given list of Dictionary (employee ID number) containing employee detail

```
ID001 ={'Name':'John Clause', 'Age':'21' , 'Gender':'Male'}    
ID002 ={'Name':'Greg Pyuse' , 'Age':'21' , 'Gender':'Male'}
```

## Populate List with dictionary"

`List = [ID001,ID002]`

## Require a user input() to ask for Dictionary i.e. 'ID001' or 'ID002'

`ID = input()`

## I want to display list index corresponding to dictionary fron user input

`ID_Index=List.index(ID)`

### If I run:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         3 
>         4 #Get the list index of ID Number
>   ----> 5 ID_Index=List.index(ID)
>         6 print(type(ID))
>         7 #Display content of list with particular index
>
> ValueError: 'ID002' is not in list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to look up an entry by a key, you should use a dict instead:

```
Dict = {
    'ID001': {'Name':'John Clause', 'Age':'21' , 'Gender':'Male'},
    'ID002': {'Name':'Greg Pyuse' , 'Age':'21' , 'Gender':'Male'}
}
```

so that you can use `Dict[ID]` to obtain the dict `{'Name':'John Clause', 'Age':'21' , 'Gender':'Male'}` if `ID` is `ID001`.

Comment: thanks, the problem can be done by dictionary. I found out it can be combined with a LIST. Its more of programming approach than a problem. I will show my resolution

Answer (score 0):

*I Elaborate my resolution base on answer by **bhlsing** for future viewers*

Define Dictionary

```
info_Dict={}
Student={}
```

Create Dictionary with three keys and values

```
for any_variable in range(0,3):
    id=input('Enter I.D. ') 

#Populate dictionary (info_Dict) with student's information using input()
    info_Dict['Name']=input("Name: ") 
    info_Dict['Age'] =input("Age: ")
    info_Dict['Course']=input("Course: ")

#Add (info_Dict) to another dictionary (Student) whose keys are student's I.D.
    Student['ID00'+id]=(info_Dict)

#Empty Dictionary of students (info_Dict) so we can add new entry 
#on next loop - it act as temporary variable.
    info_Dict={}  

print(Student)
```

If I ran, It will ask in 3 loops for inputs, I entered as follows:

```
Enter I.D. 1
Name: MATT MONROE 
Age: 88
Course: PYTHON 
Enter I.D. 2
Name: JAMES COOPER 
Age: 68
Course: JAVA 
Enter I.D. 3
Name: CATE HOLMES 
Age: 52
Course: AUTOMOTIVE 

{'ID001': {'Name': 'MATT MONROE ', 'Age': '88', 'Course': 'PYTHON '},
 'ID002': {'Name': 'JAMES COOPER ', 'Age': '68', 'Course': 'JAVA '},
 'ID003': {'Name': 'CATE HOLMES ', 'Age': '52', 'Course': 'AUTOMOTIVE '}}
```

I can now edit based on ID number

```
Student['ID002']={'NAME':input('NAME'),'Age':input('Age'), 'Course':input('Course')}
Student
```

If i run it will ask input, it will then override the previous data of ID002

```
NAMEANNE CURTIS 
Age32
CourseFINE ARTS 

{'ID001': {'Name': 'MATT MONROE ', 'Age': '88', 'Course': 'PYTHON '},
 'ID002': {'NAME': 'ANNE CURTIS ', 'Age': '32', 'Course': 'FINE ARTS '},
 'ID003': {'Name': 'CATE HOLMES ', 'Age': '52', 'Course': 'AUTOMOTIVE '}}
```